# Having troubles Installing MySQL on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mysql, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to install MySQL on a friend's computer. I selected the "full" option, and I receive this message during installation:
[image: Screenshot of MySQL]

I have installed Visual Studio though:
[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio]

However, as the friend I'm installing for is not a power user, (and due to data costs), I installed the barest minimum of Visual studio:

[image]
[image]

All the options in the above two windows are unchecked. I would like to know which options I need to select to be able to install MySQL. (If it is necessary to answer the question, I would screenshot a scrolling of the entire Visual Studio 'Modify' window).

The version of MySQL installer I'm using is: 'mysql-installer-community-5.7.18.1'
The Version of Visual Studio I installed is 'Visual Studio 2017 community'

Comment: I would suggest the "Desktop developmet with C++" option. Otherwise, just remember that MySQL doesn't require VS 2017 to be installed and the VS 2017 integration can be unselected in the MySQL installer.